# Adding Close Entry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-editor

Instead of the establishing a new short in the last line of code, I would like to exit the long position at 1 QQQ point profit.  How can I add this?

```
//@version=5
strategy("OutSide Bar Strategy", overlay=true)
if (high > high[1] and low < low[1])
if (close > open)
    strategy.entry("OutBarLE", strategy.long, comment="OutBarLE")
if (close < open)
    **strategy.entry("OutBarSE", strategy.short, comment="OutBarSE")**
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```